# Atribuir valor do Banco de Dados a uma variável c#

Tags: c#, mysql

Eu quero que o valor que eu obti do abertoCaixa seja atribuido a variavel checagem. E que depois rolasse uma verificação.
abertoCaixa é um int da minha tblCaixa, id Caixa é minha chave Primária da Tabela tblCaixa.

```
private void btnAbrirCaixa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=dbSistema;uid=root;server=localhost;pwd=");
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com.CommandText = "select abertoCaixa from tblCaixa where idCaixa = (select max(idCaixa) from tblCaixa);";
            com.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();

                int checagem;

//No caso seria aqui que a variavel "checagem" vai receber o valor do abertoCaixa

                con.Close();

                if (checagem == 2)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Paçoca");
                }


            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro:\n" + error);

            }
        }
```

Comment: recomendo utilizar o [linq](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq-queries) vai fazer exatamente o que você quer e com muito mais eficiência

Comment: sou novo com programação, que propriedade é essa?

Comment: não é uma propriedade, é uma ferramenta do c# para auxiliar nas consultas. nesse link que passei tem a introdução de como utilizar ele, tam bem escrita e vai te ajudar a iniciar da forma certa

Comment: Outra coisa você ta utlizando Ef core ou framework?

Comment: O que é esse `aberto Caixa`, que tipo ele é, que informação está aí? Precisa dar mais detalhes para podermos ajudar. Este código tem vários problemas, só resolver isto não vai adiantar.

Comment: @Tmilitino não, ele claramente não está.

Comment: @Maniero, eu sei cara xD, só queria ver se ele sabe o que é e se não orienta-lo para usar, pelo menos eu acho melhor.  Sobre sua pergunta `aberto caixa` é o retorno da `query` dele.

Comment: Eu acho pior e eu orientaria ele a não usar a não ser que tenha certeza que precisa, quase todo mundo porque está na moda e não porque precisa. Eu tenho certeza que isso é o retorno da *query*, está bem explícito no código, mas isso não quer dizer nada para saber o que fazer.

Comment: @Maniero, blz cara! valeu ai. Só mais um ponto pq você acha pior?

Comment: Isso é outro assunto, mas é pesado, lento, cheio de limitações, quase sempre cria vazamentos de abstração, coisas a mais pra aprender e ter que lidar quando tem algo fácil que funciona melhor em todos os aspectos e quando a pessoa sabe usar nem dá tanto trabalho (dá para quem só sabe seguir receita de bolo e não aprendeu programar, mas mesmo assim ainda é mais fácil)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero que te ajude, mas acredito que basta ler o registro com MySqlDataReader

```
private void btnAbrirCaixa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=dbSistema;uid=root;server=localhost;pwd=");
            MySqlCommand com = new MySqlCommand();
            com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            com.CommandText = "select abertoCaixa from tblCaixa where idCaixa = (select max(idCaixa) from tblCaixa)";
            com.Connection = con;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataReader dtreader = com.ExecuteReader();//Crie um objeto do tipo reader para ler os dados do banco

                int checagem =0 ;

                    while (dtreader.Read())//Enquanto existir dados no select
                {
                    checagem = (int)dtreader["abertoCaixa"];
                }


                con.Close();

                if (checagem == 2)
                {

                    MessageBox.Show("Paçoca");
                }


            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro:\n" + error);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, porém estava dando erro no int checagem; então fiz int checagem = 0;

Comment: Por nada... É verdade, ja ajustei na resposta... se te ajudou, marca como certo a resposta. vlw

Comment: outra duvida, como eu faço isso com where? eu quero atualizar uma coluna da maior id da tabela, porém esse codigo não funciona, eu tntei fazer: update tblCaixa set adicionadoCaixa = 32.40 where idCaixa = (select max(idCaixa) from tblCaixa);

Comment: Abra outra pergunta e amanha te ajudo. So me marca no comentario.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode resolver isso usando o `ExecuteScalar()` desta forma:

```
int checagem;
checagem = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
```

Essa função busca apenas um valor do banco e não uma coleção, como é o caso do `DataTable`.